# How to increase billable CPU time?

Tags: transactions, ram, cpu

I tried the execute a transaction to update public keys for my account. But I got the following error: `billed CPU time (857 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (165 us)`. How to increase the maximum billable CPU time so my transaction can go through?

Comment: How do I use option 3 please. Pushing to a faster node?

Answer (score 2):

1. wait a few hours and send transaction again (it will work if you used CPU before in 24 hour window)
2. stake more EOS for CPU and you can send again immediately.
3. push to faster node where you transaction will execute below limit :)
4. if it was slow node (low memory, swapping, other running processes on the server) and it was just a performance glitch, then probably you can just push it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just stake more EOS to increase the amount of CPU time you are entitled to, or you can try to find a more performant BP where your computations can be done faster.

[**system delegatebw**](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.1.0/reference#cleos-system-delegatebw)

```
Positional Arguments

    from TEXT - The account delegating bandwidth
    receiver TEXT - The account to delegate bandwidth from
    stake_net_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to delegate for network bandwidth
    stake_cpu_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to delegate for CPU bandwidth
```

Example:

```
$ cleos system delegatebw accountname1 accountname2 "1 SYS" "1 SYS"
```

Comment: Would it be `cleos system delegatebw accountname1 accountname2 "1 EOS" "1 EOS"`? Do I just need CPU bandwith in this case? How long usually does it take for the result to go through?