# billed CPU time (2064 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (477 us)

Tags: transactions

Please help. I want to sell my rex into EOS. I am not able to do it. I get the error: billed CPU time (2064 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (477 us)
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase billable CPU time?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/how-to-increase-billable-cpu-time)